# How to synchronize java threads with available memory?

Tags: java, multithreading

The snippet is a simulator for a real time issue.I have got few threads which process files. All works fine when the file size are of some 10 mb average.At times files can be of >100mb. Then there is a shortage of memory and eventually all will fail. So I was looking into a way to see if thread 2 gets a big file to process, then the other threads need to wait until the memory is freed up. So my intention is for finding a way for each thread to read the available memory before starting to do the job or sleep until memory is available.
Code is modified to make the variable v global and for having clean up thread.
Below is the code snippet for a simple Thread simulator which will throw OutOfMemoryError exception. How do I achieve to run this program without exception?

How do I communicate to each thread of the memmory crunch and put it to sleep?

How do I gracefully allow each thread to run?

```
import java.util.Vector;

public class ThreadSimulator
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
    Vector v = new Vector();

    Thread t1 = new Thread(new Runnable()
    {
      public void run()
      {
        while(true)
        {
          byte b[] = new byte[1048576];
          v.add(b);          
        }
      }
    });


    Thread t2 = new Thread(new Runnable()
    {
      public void run()
      {
        while(true)
        {
          byte b[] = new byte[1048576];
          v.add(b);          
        }
      }
    });
    Thread t3 = new Thread(new Runnable()
    {
      @Override
      public void run()
      {
        while(true)
        {
          try
          {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
          }
          catch (InterruptedException e)
          { 
            e.printStackTrace();
          }
          v.clear();         
        }
      }
    });
    t1.start();
    t2.start();
    t3.start();
  }
}
```

Comment: why do you have while true?

Comment: There really isn't such a thing as 'gracefully running out of memory' in a dynamic, memory managed  runtime like Java.

Comment: It's unclear what you want to happen here. These threads do nothing but eat up memory. What does it mean for such a thread to gracefully run?

Comment: You need to break from your while loop at some point

Comment: The snippet is a simulator for a real time issue.I have got few threads which process files. All works fine when the file size are of some 10 mb average.At times files can be of >100mb. Then there is a shortage of memory and eventually all will fail. So I was looking into a way to see if thread 2 gets a big file to process, then the other threads need to wait until the memory is freed up. So my intention is for finding a way for each thread to read the available memory before starting to do the job or sleep until memory is available. Sorry for not very clearly explaining the problem earlier

Comment: To make it more realistic , please consider the Vector a global variable and another thread cleaning it up

Comment: Don't load giant files into memory, perhaps? You just don't really have a good, reliable insight from pure Java as to when you might run out of memory so the optimal approach is conservative and prophylactic.

Comment: @maytham-ɯɐɥʇʎɐɯ.. was just trying to explain the problem to show a process which keeps running

Comment: Edited the question and snippet for more clarity. @pvg it's in consideration , but cannot be immediately changed

Comment: Well, the thing you want doesn't sound like it can be done at all so your energies are probably better spent accelerating the 'consideration'

Comment: @pvg Hmm thought so with my tiny brain :) .. But wanted to check with the bigger brains out here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to stop looping before the memory runs out, you could measure the amount of free memory and abort the thread (or better: break from the while loop) before it goes to zero.

```
MemoryMXBean memoryMxBean = ManagementFactory.getMemoryMXBean();
MemoryUsage memoryUsage = memoryMxBean.getHeapMemoryUsage();
int used = memUsage.getUsed();
int max = memUsage.getMax();
```

Comment: Considering I make the Vector v a global variable and have another thread which frees up the used memory in regular interval. Will it be possible to make the threads wait or sleep until memory becomes available?

Comment: Edited the question and snippet to reflect the same